# Doble for para buscar elementos de una lisa en una segunda lista y ejecutar resta y retorno de nuevo numero a la lista 1

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

**Buenas noches amigos:**

Tengo dos listas, quiero que ningún elemento de la primera lista se encuentre en la segunda, de ocurrir de debe restar en 1 al elemento de la primera lista y luego agregarlo nuevamente a la primera lista para que  sea evaluada nuevamente.

```
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
restringidos=[7,9,13,14,17,18, 19]

for i in numeros:
    for x in restringidos:
       if int(i) == int(x):
           i==i-1
           
        
      # else:
            
    print(i)
```

Solo he podido, listar números repetidos, pero no logro restar en una unidad y tampoco logro regresarlo a la lista original para que sea evaluada nuevamente. O también podría hacerse lo siguiente: si un número de la primera lista de encuentra en la segunda, entonces restar, luego ese nuevo numero volver evaluarlo con toda la segunda lista, hasta que no se repita.

**Muchas gracias de antemano, saludos**

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es recorrer la lista de numeros:

```
for idx in range(len(numeros)):
```

Por cada número examinar si está en los restringidos. En tal caso, restarle uno y comprobar nuevamente. Repetir hasta que no esté repetido:

```
while numeros[idx] in restringidos:
    numeros[idx] -= 1
```

No es necesario extraer o reinsertar el numero examinado; se puede operar directamente con el valor usando indices `numeros[idx]`

La solución completa:

```
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
restringidos=[7,9,13,14,17,18, 19]

print(numeros)
for idx in range(len(numeros)):
    while numeros[idx] in restringidos:
        numeros[idx] -= 1

print(numeros)
```

produce:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20]
```

Comment: Genial !!! Muchas gracias!!!, no sabia lo de "While" te agradezco mucho

Comment: Una consulta por favor: Por qué usar: for i in range(len(numeros)):  y no for i in numeros: ?

Comment: @Seele. La primera forma me entrega el indice del elemento, o sea, puedo cambiar su contenido. La segunda forma me da una copia del contenido, por lo que no puedo cambiar el original.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info!!!!